# Tracking progress

Tags: node.js, upload, stream

If I want to track the progress of a download from a server using request, I can do this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');

request('http://127.0.0.1:3000/cloud/foo/bar.mov')
  .on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('chunk size: ' + data.length)
});
```

But how do I track the progress of an upload to another server?

```
fs.createReadStream('/tmp/foo/bar.mov)
    .pipe(request.put('http://...cloud'));
```

I've looked around and there are modules that do that ("progress-stream") by creating an intermediary stream to pipe to so the code looks like this:

```
var stat = fs.statSync(filename);
var str = progress({
    length: stat.size,
    time: 100
});

str.on('progress', function(progress) {
    console.log('chunk size: ' + progress.delta);
}

fs.createReadStream('/tmp/foo/bar.mov)
  .pipe(str)
  .pipe(request.put('http://../cloud/foo.mov'));
```

It seems messy to create another stream to track the progress of what's been written to request.

Is there a better way track the progress of the upload? Most of the articles out there deal with uploading files *to* node, not *from* node.